# keep realm db after android app update

Tags: android, realm

I have a realm db stored in /data/.. folder. When I reinstall the same app version via android studio, the process keeps the data. But if I update from lower app version to higher, it removes it. What can be the reason and how to keep this db after an app update? Migration code:

```
public class FRGMigration implements RealmMigration {
@Override
public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion == 3) {
        realm.getSchema().create("Settings")
                .addField("id", Integer.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY)
                .addField("userName", String.class)
                .addField("cachePolitics", String.class)
                .addField("soundUri", String.class)
                .addField("cacheDir", String.class)
                .addField("timeStamp", Long.class);

        realm.getSchema().get("NewsItem")
                .addField("teaser", String.class);
        oldVersion++;
        SettingsDB settingsDB = DependencyProvider.getInstance().provideSettingsDB();
        Settings settings = settingsDB.getSettings();
        settings.setTimeStamp(0L);
        settingsDB.updateSettings(settings);
    }
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 37;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof FRGMigration;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

From API 23+ android OS automatically creates backup of data.
If you don't want backup to be created add this line of code to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application ...
    android:allowBackup="false">
</app>
```

You can read more on [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html) link.

Comment: I do have this parameter set to "true", but it does not help when app updates, unfortunately

Comment: @M.Maximovich Could you post your `RealmConfiguration`?

Comment: realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()                 .name("settings.realm")                 .schemaVersion(4)                 .migration(new FRGMigration())                 .build();

Comment: @M.Maximovich I would rather say that there is something wrong with your migration...

Comment: Could you try removing this part:

`SettingsDB settingsDB = DependencyProvider.getInstance().provideSettingsDB();
        Settings settings = settingsDB.getSettings();
        settings.setTimeStamp(0L);
        settingsDB.updateSettings(settings);
    }
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 37;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof FRGMigration;
}`

Comment: it did not help

Comment: Updating realm lib from 5.8.8 to 7.0.0 was dropped all data after updating app without changing scheme version.